# result of average linkage clustering on top-down and bottom-up direction

Tags: clustering

let say i want to form two clusters.

I use the " **group average linkage** ".

Hence it considers **all distances of the points between cluster A and B**.

so no matter I use merge or division approach, the result will be the same?

For example, if I got 5 data points ABCDE,

if I do division, I will always divide AB and CDE.

If I do merging, I will always merge AB, then merge CD, then merge CDE, so I get same result of AB and CDE?

I think single linkage may give different result because it is a greedy decision in the division/merging step, but **group average linkage** is different?

Comment: Are you asking whether average linkage is different from single linkage, or whether there's some stochastic choice in the later? You should also clarify the distinction you make between bottom-up (merging?) and top-down (division?). Single linkage is an agglomerative clustering method.

Comment: yes, average linkage can be used in agglomerative clustering and division clustering. I wonder if this will lead to same result, thx for advice.

Comment: I expect agglomerative and divisive algorithms are different profoundly and may yield not identical results under any linkage method.